# Why can't be Java Swing code run in Windows command line?

Tags: java, swing, cmd, command-line, java-8

Here is the Java I try to run from command line:

```
package my;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
class Login extends JFrame{
    JLabel l1,l2,l3;
    JTextField t1;
    JPasswordField t2;
    JButton b1;
    Login(){
        Font f=new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,24);
        l1=new JLabel("my.Login Page");
        l1.setFont(f);
        l2=new JLabel("UserName");
        t1=new JTextField();
        l3=new JLabel("Password");
        t2=new JPasswordField();
        b1=new JButton("my.Login");
        l1.setBounds(70,40,200,40);
        l2.setBounds(70,100,100,20);
        t1.setBounds(70,120,200,30); 
        l3.setBounds(70,170,100,20);
        t2.setBounds(70,190,200,30);
        b1.setBounds(170,240,100,30);
        add(l1);
        add(l2);
        add(t1);
        add(l3);
        add(t2);
        add(b1);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                System.out.println(t1.getText());
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(t2.getPassword()));
            }
        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Login login=new Login();
    }
}
```

with the following commands:

```
javac my\Login.java

java my.Login
```

Earlier I was able to run it when I wrote Java code in IntellIJ even in IDE and in command line, too. However, now I only can run swing Java code in IntellIJ.

When I try to run it in command line, I get the following:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class my.Login
```

Is there any mode to be able run swing codes from command line? Why do I get error when I try to run this code in command line?
I have Java 8 in my computer, Java is added to PATH.

Comment: Does the `my` directory contain `Login.class`?

Comment: Yes. It is in this package.

Comment: Check if you have env var `CLASSPATH` set to some inappropriate value and if so fix it, or explicitly override it: `java -cp . my.Login`

Comment: Does it help to add `-cp=.`?

Comment: Not sure on the crux of the question, but some comments on the code. 1) Good call for using a `JPasswordField`! 2) But don't extend or use a `JFrame` for a login. A modal `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane` works better. Just create (don't extend) a `JPanel` for the login & put that in the top level window (TLW). 3) The label seen at the top would be better as the title of the TLW. 4) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  ..

Comment: .. As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: `java -cp . my.Login` works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the line of code:

```
package my;
```

When running your program, you probably didn't specify the filepath of the package root. Assuming your filepath to the package is: `\folder\my\Login.java`, you need to change directory to `\folder` in the terminal before running the compiling and executing commands.